# Infering data types for a virtual machine with no type metadata

Tags: c++, variables, types, type-inference, vm-implementation

I'm writing a (stack-based) VM which does not include type metadata when storing variables, either in the stack, or the actual bytecode. Also, all data is stored as unsigned, where applicable (all integers and chars are stored as unsigned)

Which of the following approaches would be more efficient, considering I want to keep memory very minimal (8 bits for a bool, 16 bits for a short and so on) and don't want to bloat either the code, or working memory too much.

```
//Type info.
    enum TypeInfo {
        TYPE_INT8,    //=0
        TYPE_INT16,
        TYPE_INT32,
        TYPE_INT64,
        TYPE_STRING,
        TYPE_CHAR,
        TYPE_BOOL,
        TYPE_POINTER,
        LEFT_S_RIGHT_S,
        LEFT_U_RIGHT_U,
        LEFT_S_RIGHT_U,
        LEFT_U_RIGHT_S,
        BOTH_SAME_TYPE,
        SIGNED,
        UNSIGNED     //=14
    };
```

Using the above, I could interpret bytecode in the following way.
I have done the following in some language:

```
unsigned int one = 78888;
signed int two = -900;
signed int result = one - two;
print(result); //inferred overloaded function targeting the 'unsigned int' print function
```

So, my virtual machine assembly, something like the following could be generated:

```
PUSH32 <78888>                            //push 'one' onto stack
PUSH32 <-900 cast to an unsigned int>     //push 'two' onto stack
ADD32, TypeInfo::LEFT_U_RIGHT_S, TypeInfo::BOTH_SAME_TYPE, TypeInfo::TYPE_INT32
PRNT32, TypeInfo::SIGNED, TypeInfo::INT32
```

Which would be a better approach: this, or storing the data about the type (probably just one extra byte) with the variable itself? It seems like a lot of bloating to store the variable along with its data, both in code AND memory, as its used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is fairly opinion based. But I prefer the idea that types are language concept and should only exist at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give you a full analysis, as only a part of your intent is known. But in case it could help, here some thoughts.

As always, you'll have to make a trade-off between speed and space:

- if you'd store the type with the variable, the VM data will be larger.  The op-codes of you VM engine would however be smaller (no extra parameter for the operation, as they could be deduced from type info), so that in the end, the overall memory footprint could be smaller.  At runtime however, every op-code would have to analyse the types of its arguments, decide on conversions (in case of mixed types).  So execution might be slower.
- if you'd store the variables without type, the data will be smaller.  But the op-code will need additional parameters (here, ADD32 has 3 parameters, as you already identified).  So the code will be bigger.  On execution time however you could go faster.
- you could optimize further this second option, by making opcodes including the parameters (that's the way most modern non-RISK CPU instruction sets are designed).  So instead of having for example one instruction ADD32 (1 byte code) with 3 parameters (3 extra bytes? ), you could have several specialized and optimized opcodes (with a nice bit organisation that takes into account op-code fields it could even be organize in 2 bytes).

Note that the second and the third approach require strong typing in the source language that you convert to your VM.  If you want to have dynamic types, you'd need the first approach.